# Getting props in reagent's :reagent-render function

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I Javascript's version of react I can use

```
  this.props
```

but what can I use to gave props in

```
  :reagent-render
```

callback?

[I am trying to do as done here](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/rrag/react-stockcharts-examples2/tree/master/examples/AreaChart) in Chart.js line 14.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question, you can access the `component` and `props` in `reagent-render` by doing something like this

```
(ns chartly.core
  (:require
    [reagent.ratom :as ra]
    [reagent.core :as r]))

(defn data-fn [implicit-this]
  ;; use implicit-this as needed, which is equivalent to "this"
  ;; From create-class docs -
  ;;    :component-did-mount (fn [this])
 )

(defn chart-render []
  (let [comp     (r/current-component)     ;; Reagent method
        r-props  (r/props comp)            ;; Reagent method
        js-props (.-props (clj->js comp))]
      (js/console.log "PROPS" r-props)     ;;--  etc...
    [:div {:style {:width 100}}]))

(def data (ra/atom {})) ;;--> see more info on reagent-atom

(defn chart-component []
  (r/create-class
   {:component-did-mount data-fn
    :display-name "chart-component"
    :reagent-render chart-render}))

    To use - 
    [chart-component]
```

However, this is anti-pattern and will be quite difficult to manage, since you are trying to update data prop internally with `component-did-mount`, which, on completion, would need to manually signal the `React component` to update itself.

One of the features of Reagent is that is offers to  detect changes and updating the component, usually using `atom`. See [Managing State in Reagent](https://reagent-project.github.io/) for more info.

What you are looking to do is exactly what the [Re-frame Framework](https://github.com/Day8/re-frame) is helping to manage. You set-up a data-store, and when the store changes, it signals to subscribers (React elements) to update accordingly, and you don't have to handle the signal changes yourself.

There are some edge cases where tapping into the lifecyle events are necessary, especially with charts and other drawing libraries, but I might recommend re-visiting if you find reagent `atoms` and/or the `re-frame library` insufficient for your needs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you accept some Hiccup data from a user as a string, right? And then try to evaluate it into `user` namespace, where only `reagent` library is loaded?

First, the more you build your further code to evaluate, the more difficult to understand it becomes. You could use something like this:

```
(binding [*ns* user-ns] (eval (read-string user-data)))
```

Also, to prevent wrong input, it would be better to validate user's input either with Schema or clojure.spac libraries. Since read-string returns a data structure, it might be checked with those two as well. So you would see an error before starting to evaluate something.